# Java apache fop 2.2 incorrect rendering of some cyrillic characters

Tags: java, pdf, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I got stuck with a problem that I can't resolve myself.
I tried to simplify source code as much as I could and here is what I came up with - https://www.dropbox.com/s/ey3f65c4iby7ccn/fop_example.zip.

Here is the main piece of code (code of the template)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" font-family="Arial">
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simpleA4" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm">
                <fo:region-body reference-orientation="0"/>
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simpleA4">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <fo:block-container>
                    <fo:block>
                        ИмяпассажираКУЛЬДЮШЕВАЛИЯАЛЕКСАНДРОВНАДокументудостоверяющийличностьНомербилетаДоСОЧИСОЧРейсИЖВылетАВГКлассЭРЕГ№ВАЖНАЯИНФОРМАЦИЯ
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:block-container>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

I can't simplify this long text because if I remove any character everything will work fine. 
So the problem is with the last letters. Instead of "ИНФОРМАЦИЯ" I get "ИНФОРМ~ИЯ" and if I remove or add any other cyrillic letter everything will be ok, so I guess the problem isn't with fonts.

[image]

Why's that? Please help me, I have no idea what's wrong or how to fix it.

P.S. Here is a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6whau1su16ow6dn/result.pdf?dl=0) to the resulting pdf, maybe you could say what's wrong by simply looking at this file.

P.P.S Tried to replace this text with `&#x0418;&#x043c;&#x044f;&#x043f;&#x0430;&#x0441;&#x0441;&#x0430;&#x0436;&#x0438;&#x0440;&#x0430;&#x041a;&#x0423;&#x041b;&#x042c;&#x0414;&#x042e;&#x0428;&#x0415;&#x0412;&#x0410;&#x041b;&#x0418;&#x042f;&#x0410;&#x041b;&#x0415;&#x041a;&#x0421;&#x0410;&#x041d;&#x0414;&#x0420;&#x041e;&#x0412;&#x041d;&#x0410;&#x0414;&#x043e;&#x043a;&#x0443;&#x043c;&#x0435;&#x043d;&#x0442;&#x0443;&#x0434;&#x043e;&#x0441;&#x0442;&#x043e;&#x0432;&#x0435;&#x0440;&#x044f;&#x044e;&#x0449;&#x0438;&#x0439;&#x043b;&#x0438;&#x0447;&#x043d;&#x043e;&#x0441;&#x0442;&#x044c;&#x041d;&#x043e;&#x043c;&#x0435;&#x0440;&#x0431;&#x0438;&#x043b;&#x0435;&#x0442;&#x0430;&#x0414;&#x043e;&#x0421;&#x041e;&#x0427;&#x0418;&#x0421;&#x041e;&#x0427;&#x0420;&#x0435;&#x0439;&#x0441;&#x0418;&#x0416;&#x0412;&#x044b;&#x043b;&#x0435;&#x0442;&#x0410;&#x0412;&#x0413;&#x041a;&#x043b;&#x0430;&#x0441;&#x0441;&#x042d;&#x0420;&#x0415;&#x0413;&#x2116;&#x0412;&#x0410;&#x0416;&#x041d;&#x0410;&#x042f;&#x0418;&#x041d;&#x0424;&#x041e;&#x0420;&#x041c;&#x0410;&#x0426;&#x0418;&#x042f;`, still get the same result.

Text with only problem characters presented in unicode:

```
ИмяпассажираКУЛЬДЮШЕВАЛИЯАЛЕКСАНДРОВНАДокументудостоверяющийличностьНомербилетаДоСОЧИСОЧРейсИЖВылетАВГКлассЭРЕГ№ВАЖНАЯИНФОРМ&#x0410;&#x0426;&#x0418;Я
```

I managed to do the example even shorter:

```
ИмяпсжираКУЛЬДЮШЕВАЯкудсвющийличньорбилетаСЧВыЭГ№ЖНФОРМАЦИЯ
```

Comment: sounds like a encoding issue to me? Either that or Java has not got the supported character sets installed?

Comment: Well at first I though that's the case. But 1) everything is in UTF-8 and the embedded font supports cyrillic characters 2) If I add or remove something everything will work fine.

Comment: 1) I meant does java running with `nsl_lang` environment variable set to UTF8 also? Try print these characters into the console and see that has been encoded.  2) Can you expand more on what you mean by `add or remove something`?

Comment: 2) For example I can remove just one letter Э from this text and ИНФОРМАЦИЯ will be displayed correctly.

Comment: >Try print these characters into the console and see that has been encoded. 
Everything is printed fine as expected.

Comment: I also tried this string with full Russian alphabet in my template - "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ" and everything is displayed correctly as well. Just that exact character sequence from my post isn't displayed properly and I can't understand why.

Comment: And I added NLS_LANG="RUSSIAN_RUSSIA.UTF8" to /etc/environment, logged out and logged back in. Still I get the same incorrect result.

Comment: one other thing to try would be, instead of printing the characters, try prints the unicode just for the comparison? If its just one or two characters then perhaps those are special characters e.g. the Euro symbol which got introduced late in the UTF-8.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what I should do :( It's one or two characters, yes, but they are not special characters, just regular cyrillic letters. And they are printed well if I remove something from this line of text.

Comment: try reorder the characters? perhaps the combine of characters triggered some special case? I meant to printout the unicode of the characters rather than the character itself.

Comment: If I reorder them I still get incorrect result, but it looks differently. Gonna try unicode now.

Comment: I tried unicode of the characters instead of the characters, result is still the same :( I added unicoded version to my post.

Comment: can you tried with just the problem characters? very hard to see the difference.

Comment: Added to the post this text with only incorrectly displayed characters encoded in unicode (&#x0410;&#x0426;&#x0418;).

Comment: I managed to do the example even shorter: ИмяпсжираКУЛЬДЮШЕВАЯкудсвющийличньорбилетаСЧВыЭГ№ЖНФОРМАЦИЯ

Comment: Do you get any warning / error message using fop from the command line? I tried your example mapping the font to Arial, and the output seems correct.

Comment: No warnings or errors. Did you use Arial font from my archive?

Comment: Tried with that and with my system one: in both cases, the result seemed correct. Really strange.

Comment: There is a pdf in the post generated by my computer. Can you please open it?

Comment: I confirm that the text in your pdf is different from what I get.

Comment: That's weird. Maybe there are some extra parameters (environment variables or parameter from fop config) that need to be specified or default values are taken otherwise (and these default values are different for our computers)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the problem was because of the incorrect encoding mode.

```
<font kerning="yes" embed-url="/arial.ttf" encoding-mode="single-byte">
    <font-triplet name="Arial" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
</font>
```

I should have used *cid* instead of *single-byte* because I embed .ttf (TrueType) and according to [the documentation](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.2/fonts.html) default (and I think that means preferable) option is

> "cid" for Truetype, "single-byte" for Type 1

Hovewer, I suppose it'a bug of the library, because if I want to embed the font completely I have to use the *single-byte* mode.

> When embedding TrueType (ttf) or TrueType Collections (ttc), a subset
>   of the original font, containing only the glyphs used, is embedded in
>   the output document. That's the default, but if you specify
>   encoding-mode="single-byte" (see above), the complete font is
>   embedded.